# Android Firebase obtaining the last push key in a database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a chat app using `Firebase` and am looking for some help or clarification. So my `Database` is structured below. Under the `ChatID` node are random `push IDs` that each contain some information which get made everytime a message is sent. Is it possible to get the last `push ID` automatically so I can obtain only the information stored in that push key? I have seen using `orderbykey` but not sure if that would work.

**Database Structure**

```
Chat
 -ChatID
    -LIYv8kWHEZ7udgM048U
    -LIYv9t5jNmR8RXPht-p
    -LIYxzbhbfkItT3FAsWB
       createdByUser: "T3Wb0pHSfCTaIA2ofQSxc915wK83"
       text: "Hey"
       timestamp: "Aug 19"
    -LIaJaAGG-jwD0i_bAqL
       createdByUser: "T3Wb0pHSfCTaIA2ofQSxc915wK83"
       text: "Yoooo"
       timestamp: "Aug 20"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do the following

```
    chatRef.orderByChild("ChatID").limitToLast(1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String key  = dataSnapshot.getKey();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

Where `chatRef`

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase,chatRef;
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
chatRef = mDatabase.child("Chat");
```

Comment: Maybe more `databaseReference.child("Chat/"+ ChatID).limitToLast(1)` ?

Comment: yes, also if databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();  the code of Julien is the same.

Comment: I'd expect `chatRef.child("ChatID").orderByKey.limitToLast(1)`.

Comment: @gaston I followed what you did, didn't seem to work. For some reason my key value is equal to "Chat". When I removed the orderbychild my key value then was just my "chatid". Couldn't get the push ID so I could obtain the timestamp of the last one in my database

Comment: Yes I've tried all the answers posted, each time it is just giving me the chatID I already have and not the push keys that are inside the chat ID. I just tried this way, databaseReference.child("Chat/"+ ChatID).limitToLast(1)... My key ends up = ChatID.

Comment: try to do the way frank answered there and in the snapshot just get the value, String key = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

Comment: It semi works but it gets me the push ID plus all the data inside as one string. If I try to do datasnapshot.child("timestamp").getvalue.tostring I just a null response

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve using this

```
    final DatabaseReference ChatDB = mDatabaseChat.child("ChatID");
    final Query lastQuery = ChatDB.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    ChatDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
              lastQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       for(DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                           String key = child.child("text").getValue().toString();
```